# Add "Add new content" custom block to a specific page

Tags: 8, blocks

I would like to add a block which contain a button for when the user click would redirect to the Add new content page with a specific content type.

I'm building some sort of a book store a would like to let users (Anonymous, Logged-in users) to be able to upload content of a specific type to be featured in that page (once approved of course).

For now, I can only list contents added by admin or anyone with the permission but using the default Add new content menu.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already given anonymous and authenticated users permission to create new content of the content type, you can simply add the link in the block.

If you're creating a custom block through the admin interface, you can make the link as you normally would.

For example, if you want to add a link to the **page** content type,

`<a href="/node/add/page">Add a page</a>`

For node content types, the link pattern is `/node/add/CONTENT_TYPE_ID`.

For taxonomy, it's `/admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/TAXONOMY_VOCAB_ID/add`.

The easy way to find these links is to navigate to the add content page and then copy the link.

Comment: Thanks. Trying your suggestions